# Not able to connect with SignalR hub using websockets transport type

Tags: angular, signalr, angular6, azure-service-fabric

I have an angular6 / Material design application . I'm trying to connect to a webservice(Service Fabric + .net core) using signalR . But i get the following error ( i've tried in Firefox and in Chrome) :

> "Error: Failed to start the transport 'WebSockets': undefined"
>
> "Error: Failed to start the connection: Error: Unable to initialize any of the available transports."

In Chrome , I also have this error in addition to the 2 previous ones ( in the example i replaced the token by xxx):

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://localhost:20003/supervisor?id=xxxx&access_token=xxxx' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid credentials available

Here is my angular code :

```
//Creating Connection
this.hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl(this.hubUrl, {
                accessTokenFactory: () => {
                  return window.localStorage.getItem('token'); }
                  , transport: (HttpTransportType.WebSockets)})
            .configureLogging(LogLevel.Information)
            .build();   
//Starting Connection 
 this.hubConnection
        .start()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('connection succeeded')
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log('Error while establishing connection  ', e);
        });
```

In my webservice , i have added in startup.cs the following code:

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
        {
            builder
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials();
        }));

//in configure() method
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseWebSockets();
app.UseAuthentication();
```

Please let me know if there is a way to fix this issue

Comment: Try adding `skipNegotiation: true` in with your `transport` option. Like this: `transport: (HttpTransportType.WebSockets), skipNegotiation: true`.

Comment: @R.Richards This fixed my issue but then the connection will only uses WebSockets, correct?

Comment: @C.M. That is true. With this setup, no other transport type will be used; only WebSockets. This has worked well for me in several applications.